# How to remap control up in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

Newer versions of org-mode remap C-up to `org-backward-paragraph`.

I would like C-up not to be remapped (and continue to use the standard Emacs' `backward-paragraph` instead).

But the standard ways of avoiding this remap do not work with org-mode (i.e., `(local-unset-key [C-up])` and `(define-key org-mode-map [C-up] 'backward-paragraph)`) don't do anything).  It seems that org-mode achieves this by remapping functions, not key bindings.

How to disable org-mode from remapping C-up?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Org mode [remaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html#Remapping-Commands) all bindings of `forward-paragraph` and `backward-paragraph` to their Org counterparts with the following code which is executed when `org.el` is loaded:

```
(org-defkey org-mode-map [remap forward-paragraph] 'org-forward-paragraph)
(org-defkey org-mode-map [remap backward-paragraph] 'org-backward-paragraph)
```

You can undo this by overriding the remappings after `org.el` is loaded.

```
(defun org-take-back-paragraph-bindings ()
  (define-key org-mode-map [remap backward-paragraph] nil)
  (define-key org-mode-map [remap forward-paragraph] nil))
(eval-after-load "org" '(org-take-back-paragraph-bindings))
```

Comment: Something I only noticed recently is that the form you pass to `eval-after-load` can be a function. Hence in this scenario you could use: `(eval-after-load "org" #'org-take-back-paragraph-bindings)`