# Make C-S-up handle shift selection under Org-Mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, cua-mode, shift-selection

When `shift-select-mode` is on (Emacs' default), `C-S-up` in text mode selects the previous paragraph.

This does not work under Org-Mode, where `C-S-up` gets translated into `C-up`, which is mapped to `org-backward-paragraph` and just moves up, but does not select the paragraph.

The question is how to enable shift selection for `C-S-up`.

The solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/how-to-remap-control-up-in-org-mode/3999) is not ideal, as it relies on `backward-paragraph` (instead of `org-backward-paragraph`), which does not work well with several Org-mode constructs (e.g., doesn't treat bullet points as paragraphs).

**PS:** I'm using `org-support-shift-select` and `org-replace-disputed keys`, like this:

```
(setq org-support-shift-select t
      org-replace-disputed-keys t)
(setq org-disputed-keys
      '(
        ([(shift left)]          . [(meta -)])         ; change status (todo/closed/done)
        ([(shift right)]         . [(meta =)])         ;
        ([(shift up)]            . [(control meta -)]) ; change priority
        ([(shift down)]          . [(control meta =)]) ;
        ([(control shift right)] . [(meta +)])         ; status of group
        ([(control shift left)]  . [(meta _)])         ;
        ([(control shift up)]    . [(control meta +)]) ; change clock logs
        ([(control shift down)]  . [(control meta _)]) ;
        ))
```

Comment: The entire world of Emacs, except for me, bends over backwards to not touch any of the internal functions except to the extent of applying an `advice`.  It sounds like you just want to add an interactive code `"^"` to `org-backward-paragraph` so that native shift-select works.  You might want to play around with modifying that function in a scratch buffer and see if you can get it to do what you want -- the interactive statement [to enable native shift-select] would look like this:  `(interactive "^")` instead of `(interactive)`.

Comment: In my own setup, I have modified `org-backward-element` in the manner mentioned in the previous comment and that is what I use instead of `org-backward-paragraph`.  I do the same thing with `org-forward-element`.  And, I bind them to M-up/M-down and just hold down the shift key if I want native shift-selection.

Answer (score 1):

Based on clues from lawlist's comments, reading around the area of "Key Sequence Input" in the elisp info file, and an explanation of `defadvice` that even I can understand, [here](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/01/22/), I added this to my .emacs:

```
(defadvice org-backward-paragraph
    (before set-up-shift-select-backward-paragraph activate)
  (interactive "^"))
(defadvice org-forward-paragraph
    (before set-up-shift-select-forward-paragraph activate)
  (interactive "^"))
```

This gives a similar effect to using `C-S-up` and `C-S-down` in text-mode.  The difference that I see is where point winds up.

This code causes calls to `org-backward-paragraph` and `org-forward-paragraph` to first call `interactive` with the magic character `^`, which means to set up `shift-select`.

I am also using `org-replace-disputed-keys`, but that didn't help with paragraphs.